# What does it mean to "interrupt movement"

Tags: civilization-board-game

In Sid Meier's Civilization, the **Communism** technology allows another players' movement to be interrupted to prevent figures from leaving a specific square.

What exactly does this mean, does this mean that if my opponent says I'm moving from here to there to attack you, and I spend the **Spy** resource to interrupt movement, I make him stay in his original square?

Or does it mean that my opponent must always move his figures 1 square at a time, and I play the **Spy** resource to stop him in his tracks as he moves?

Is there an official answer to this somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may interrupt the figures movement **in any place between the starting point and ending point**. Including the starting and ending points.

This can be argued **[By the official FAQ (v.2.0)](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/civilization/news/Civilization%20FAQ_v2.0.pdf)**

> Q:
>   If a player has the
>   Navigation
>   tech and is moving a figure
>   across water but **cannot end in water**, and his opponent
>   stops that figure’s movement in a water square using the
>   resource ability on the
>   **Communism**
>   tech, what happens?
>
> A:
>   **The figure stops in the water square**. In this case, the
>   resource ability on the
>   Communism
>   tech overrides the rule
>   that figures cannot end their movement in water

In this case, the moving player was *intented to move from the other side of the lake/river to the other side*. The movement was *interrupted* with the spy **between the starting and the ending point.**

---

**In practice**, if for example my friend is attacking me in his turn, coming from 5 tiles away and says "*draw your cards, I'll attack you*", I would respond *"hold on a second, mate. I'll got a spy in you camp.. ;).Now just say that which route you used to come over here..?*". He now shows the route and I use my spy and say "*This is the place where my spy came in and interrupted your movement*".

---

The [Itchi](http://boardgamegeek.com/user/Itchi)s huge summary of [Official and Unofficial rules and clarifications](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/98422/civilization-summary-official-and-unofficial-rules) in BGG has more notes on the Communism tech.

Answer (score 1):

You make him stay at original place. You can do this to any figure, even if the figure is planning to attack someone else and not you. The reason it says "may interrupt a movement" is that you are allowed to use this ability out of your turn, when someone else is doing the movement you can interrupt them. You dont necessarily have to use this ability in your own movement turn.

Comment: I already know that it can be used out of my turn. That wasn't the question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question was the first sentence "You make him stay at original place". So for that entire turn, the figure cant move.

Comment: How do you know that the opponent isn't supposed to move his figures one square at a time, and then when I 'interrupt' him, he stops his figures, and doesn't return them to the original location?

Answer (score 0):

The spy operates to prevent movement into the first **land** square that it controls.

If your piece is starting on land, your spy can prevent it from moving to any adjacent land square, thereby "freezing" it in place.

If your piece is starting on sea, the spy can prevent it from "landing" (that is reaching any available land square). It has to remain at sea, overriding other rules that say that it is not supposed to remain at sea.

Comment: Where exactly does it tell that it must be a _land_ square?

Comment: @np8: Spies operate on land.